# How to create a BACnet client in C

Tags: c, network-programming, protocols, network-protocols, bacnet

I am trying to create a client in C that will talk with a BACnet server. This BACnet server is stored on an industrial device (CAN2GO) and I am not sure how I could talk with this device.

I spent quite some time reading documentation for BACnet and I never found a clear example for a BACnet client. I already did some server and clients using TCP and UDP but I don't know how to start this BACnet client and I must say I am getting quite desperate.

I found a library which seems to correspond to what I want which is called [BACnet protocol stack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bacnet/) but when I tried the whois exemple no device was found (I expected to found the bacnet server but maybe I shouldn't ?).

So my question is : could you give me an exemple in C, or another language but C would be better, that would communicate with a BACnet server (nothing complicated just a question and analysing response). This example could be using the library I just wrote about or if you prefer another library I am of course open to everything. 
Thank you very much for your time and answers.

Comment: Here is a ***[link to an example where BACnet client and server applications are included](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bacnet/files/bacnet-tools/)***

Answer (score 1):

I have used that stack and it is the best open source one you are going to find. If you cannot see anything using the `demo\whois\bacwi` example from that library, then there is something wrong with your setup. In particular, are you using IP? Are your BACnet client and BACnet server on *different* machines (they cannot be on the same without some serious tweaking)? Are the two machines on the same IP subnet? (They must be, once again, unless you do some serious tweaking (in this case, setting up BBMDs (BACnet Broadcast Management Devices))).

You will also want to try the "Read Property" example (`demo\readprop\bacrp.exe`) to actually read a value from the server.

If you are still stuck, then post your detailed problem at the link on Sourceforge, Steve, the author, is *very* responsive to questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and taking the time to help me. I already tried to use demo\whois\bacwi. This program tells me that there is 0 devices found. But when I checked the network with tcpdump, I saw that there was a message coming from my computer and going to the BACnet server. This BACnet server then sends 8 message (wrapped in UDP) to my machine to answer (there are 8 devices linked to my BACnet server) but the program bacwi doesn't seem to understand anything because it tells me no devices. I don't understand why and where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using the stack - just started. I had a little trouble at first, not sure if my problem is the same but.. I basically am using some BAC components made from Schneider Electric (UNC-500) and an old un-supported platform (Niagara R2). On my laptop I created a host server and addressed it to a private LAN network between it and the UNC. My laptop was also using wifi, which was utilizing DHCP, so I had two separate interfaces going. This was my problem. I couldn't read or get 'I-AM' responses back from the UNC. As soon as I turned the WIFI off, I got the 'I-AM' broadcasts. Make sure that you are on the same network as your device, and that there are not other interfaces active. Maybe there is a way to assign the interface to use, IDK. I just started using it.